# Formula to Concatenate All Combinations of Values Two Columns Without VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I did some digging and couldn't find a similar question.  This is easy enough with a VBA loop, but really trying to get the same result with cell formulas only due to compatibility/online sharing.

I have two columns and am trying to concatenat all possible values of the two.

```
Col1  Col2
A     1
B     2
C
...etc...
```

So the result is:

```
A1
A2
B1
B2
C1
C2
...etc...
```

Ideally looking for a solution that spills so I don't have to drag down a formula, but open to any suggestion that gets the desired result.

TYIA!

Comment: Very closely related: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71456528/9758194)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Office 365 Beta Channel:

`=TOCOL(A1:A3&TRANSPOSE(B1:B2))`

Excel 2019 and later, though not suitable for large ranges:

`=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,A1:A3&TRANSPOSE(B1:B2))&"</b></a>","//b")`

Comment: I thought of `FilterXML`  but I couldn't get it to be dynamic. Your result won't hold if the number of rows in either column changes, which was something OP noted would be ideal.

Comment: @pgSystemTester It's very easy to make dynamic ranges. In fact, I assumed that the OP would know how to do that, so I left it out. I can show you if you're not sure how? Otherwise, we could wait to see if the OP also needs help in that area.

Comment: yeah I actually looked at your formula again not too long after I commented and realized I could just do vector formula. -- this seems to be the best of both worlds:
 `=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A),1)&TRANSPOSE(B1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B),1)))&"</b></a>","//b")`  Nice answer.

Comment: Thank you both!  Jos, `TOCOL` worked perfectly and is definitely the most concise and elegant solution here.  When I tried the `FILTERXML` version it caused a resource allocation error.  pgSystemTester your take on `FILTERXML` did the trick as well (plus your 'Index' version below.)

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Nov 2023**

Here's a simplified formula using the latest functions that only requires the inputs of ranges put in once, in this case columns `A:A` and `B:B`

```
=LET(first_Range,A:A,second_Range,B:B,TOCOL(FILTER(first_Range,first_Range<>"")
&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(second_Range,second_Range<>""))))
```

**Original Answer**

If you're starting in cell `A1` then this formula should work. It spills.

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),1,1,1)/COUNTA(B:B),0),1)
&INDEX(B:B,MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),1,0,1),COUNTA(B:B))+1,1)
```

[image]