# MS excel calculate sum by conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 134 | 1 |
| 432 | 2 |
| 222 | 3 |
| 21 | 4 |
| 982 | 5 |
| 1352 | 8 |
| 111 | 9 |

I need to find all possible sum combinations of col1 values IF col2 sum is 10. (5+4+1, 2+3+5, etc.) & number of terms is 3

Please advice how to solve this task?

Comment: You best implement a macro for this. Loop through col2 to find all triples that summ up to 10. then add their col1 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all unique possible sums based on a give count of items in col2 **and** sum of col2 is a specific amount, with ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(inp,B1:B7,cnt,3,sm,10,B,COUNTA(inp),A,MAKEARRAY(B,cnt,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(inp,r,1))),D,B^cnt,E,UNIQUE(MAKEARRAY(D,cnt,LAMBDA(rw,cl,INDEX(IF(A="","",A),MOD(CEILING(rw/(D/(B^cl)),1)-1,B)+1,cl)))),F,FILTER(E,MMULT(--(E<>""),SEQUENCE(cnt,,,0))=cnt),G,FILTER(F,BYROW(F,LAMBDA(a,(SUM(a)=sm)*(COUNT(UNIQUE(a,1))=cnt)))),UNIQUE(BYROW(G,LAMBDA(a,SUM(XLOOKUP(a,inp7,A1:A7))))))
```

You can now change parameters `cnt` and `sm` to whichever amount you like.

The trick is borrowed from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71189766/9758194) to calculate all permutations first. Instead of a range, the single column input is extended using `MAKEARRAY()`.

---

A short visual representation of what is happening:

1. Expand the given array based on `cnt`;

[image]

2. Create a complete list of all possible permutations;

[image]

3. Filter step 2 based on a sum per row and unique numbers (don't use values from col2 more than once);

[image]

4. Lookup each value per row to create a total sum per row;

[image]

5. Return only the unique summations as per screenshot at the top.

Comment: could you please check the formula, I got an error :"There is a problem with formula"