# How to transpose multiple rows and concatenate new column names in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, concatenation, transpose

I'm trying to figure out a way to do a combination of transposing rows into one long table, but with the row names of the long table concatenated with header and 1st row names. Basically trying to find a formula that will take this:

| duration | NJ | NY | NV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30daynew | 3 | 5 | 10 |
| 30dayrepeat | 35 | 55 | 5 |
| 30daysubscribe | 50 | 90 | 9 |

And put it into this:

| NJ-30daynew | NJ-30daysrepeat | NJ_30daysubscribe | NY-10days | NY-30daysrepeat | NY_30daysubscribe | NV-10days | NV-30daysrepeat | NV_30daysubscribe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 35 | 50 | 5 | 55 | 90 | 10 | 5 | 9 |

Sample data available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zr32yLOH8GPfeHQYjvqNuDZsLVsixcLVjlzSHcXSIj0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

### Transform Data: Transpose and Join

**Efficient: `INDEX/SEQUENCE`**

```
=LET(data,A1:E4,lDel,"-",
    rl,TOROW(DROP(TAKE(data,,1),1)),
    cl,DROP(TAKE(data,1),,1),
    v,TOROW(DROP(data,1,1),,1),
    rc,COLUMNS(rl),cc,COLUMNS(cl),c,rc*cc,
    rs,MOD((SEQUENCE(,c)-1),rc)+1,
    cs,INT((SEQUENCE(,c)-1)/cc)+1,
    l,INDEX(cl,,cs)&lDel&INDEX(rl,,rs),
VSTACK(l,v))
```

[image]

**Easy: `REDUCE/HSTACK`**

```
=LET(data,A1:E4,lDel,"-",
    rl,TOROW(DROP(TAKE(data,,1),1)),
    cl,DROP(TAKE(data,1),,1),
    v,TOROW(DROP(data,1,1),,1),
    l,DROP(REDUCE("",cl,LAMBDA(rr,c,
        HSTACK(rr,c&lDel&rl))),,1),
VSTACK(l,v))
```

Answer (score 0):

`=VSTACK(TOROW(B1:D1&"-"&A2:A4),TOROW(B2:D4))`

Or in the order as defined: `=VSTACK(TOROW(B1:D1&"-"&A2:A4,,1),TOROW(B2:D4,,1))`

If you combine (`&`) a row of values to a column of values, it iterates through the combinations.

Or more dynamic:

```
=LET(range,  A1:D4,
     a,      DROP(range,,1),
     x,      TAKE(a,1),
     data,   DROP(a,1),
     y,      DROP(TAKE(range,,1),1),
VSTACK(TOROW(x&"-"&y,,1),TOROW(data,,1)))
```

*More advanced example of the same principle:*
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76360221/12634230