# SQL CROSS APPLY in Excel Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset that is around 10 columns wide by around 50 rows deep.  This smaller example of my data set can be used to illustrate the challenge.

| Calendar | PersonnelArea | PayScaleGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VICTORIA | AU01,AU02 | PSG1 |
| NSW | AU03 | PSG2,PSG3 |
| QUEENSLAND | AU04,AU05,AU06 | PSG4,PSG5 |

In SQL, I can load that data up into a table (or in line as shown below) and I can use this SQL query ...

```
SELECT 
    OriginalRowNo,
    Calendar,
    TRIM(PersonnelArea.value) AS PersonnelArea,
    TRIM(PayScaleGroup.value) AS PayScaleGroup
FROM (
    SELECT OriginalRowNo = 1, Calendar = 'VICTORIA', PersonnelArea = 'AU01,AU02', PayScaleGroup = 'PSG1' UNION ALL
    SELECT OriginalRowNo = 2, Calendar = 'NSW', PersonnelArea = 'AU03', PayScaleGroup = 'PSG2,PSG3' UNION ALL
    SELECT OriginalRowNo = 3, Calendar = 'QUEENSLAND', PersonnelArea = 'AU04,AU05,AU06', PayScaleGroup = 'PSG4,PSG5'
) AS A
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(PersonnelArea, ',') AS PersonnelArea
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(PayScaleGroup, ',') AS PayScaleGroup
```

... to produce a fully exploded view of the data delimited by comma in each relevant column ...

[image: SQL Result]

So my question is ...

**How can I accomplish this task in Excel solely utilising formulas (VBA, PowerQuery and OfficeScripts are not suitable for my situation) rather than resorting to SQL?**

I should note as well that the original order of data should remain the same.  If the order of the data changes, it will not be fit for purpose.

I've dabbled but nothing is even coming close to the required solution.  I simply can't work out how to apply the relevant formulas dynamically across all rows and columns to make the explosion work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

## Update

Apologies but this dataset is closer to the real thing.  I didn't think double up calendars would need consideration but they do within the answers that have been provided.

| Calendar | PersonnelArea | PayScaleGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VICTORIA | AU01,AU02 | PSG1 |
| NSW | AU03 | PSG2,PSG3 |
| NSW | AU07 | PSG6 |
| QUEENSLAND | AU04,AU05,AU06 | PSG4,PSG5 |

Comment: Just to scope the problem a bit, would you potentially have more than two columns that need expanding, or is it just two as in the example?

Comment: @TomSharpe you’ll see the first paragraph in the question says I have about 10 columns. I don’t see that changing but the rows will definitely need to be dynamic.

Comment: OK I think you could do it from first principles with nested lambdas, split, hstack, vstack... but haven't had chance to try it yet

Comment: Looking forward to your attempt @TomSharpe 

Answer (score 2):

With TEXTJOIN/TEXTSPLIT this is possible, but I still recommend using power query, since you may reach the character limit of TEXTJOIN.
That said, this is a possible solution:

Create name `UNPIVOT` in the name manager and paste this in the *refers to* section:
`LAMBDA(range,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&REDUCE(TAKE(range,,1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(range)-1),LAMBDA(x,y,TOCOL(x&","&TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(x,","),TAKE(range,,1),INDEX(DROP(range,,1),,y)),",",SEQUENCE(,MAX(1+LEN(range)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range,",",""))))),","),2))),",",SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(range))),","))`

You could now use `UNPIVOT(A2:C4)` or whatever number of rows/columns.

formula used for testing:
`=LET(UNPIVOT,LAMBDA(range,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&REDUCE(TAKE(range,,1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(range)-1),LAMBDA(x,y,TOCOL(x&","&TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(x,","),TAKE(range,,1),INDEX(DROP(range,,1),,y)),",",SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(range)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range,",",""))))),","),2))),",",SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(range))),",")),UNPIVOT(A2:C4))`

[image]

It's a LAMBDA function that has a range as an input. The initial value of the formula is the first column of the input range; the next column is split horizontally by the comma delimiter and since it's joined with an `&`-operator it will copy the previous calculated values to the horizontally split values of the same row.
If we flatten them using `TOCOL` we have a column the size of the initial column values times the splitted values of the column next to it containing their joined strings (I used a comma between the joined strings).

If we loop through the columns, the size of the rows will keep expanding.

The final result is wrapped in textsplit and textafter: `TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&calculated_array,sequence(columns(,input_range))),",")`
This will split the joined strings horizontally, since they where all joined into one column.

EDIT:
Since there was a possibility of duplicate values in the first column, using XLOOKUP would return the first found column values matching the value  in column 1 for all, skipping the other values that may be there.

Therefore I first added a sequence of the number of rows for the range. This is being used for looking up the row index:

```
=LET(UNPIVOT,LAMBDA(range,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(REDUCE(SEQUENCE(ROWS(range))&","&TAKE(range,,1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(range)-1),LAMBDA(x,y,TOCOL(x&","&TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(x,","),""&SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),INDEX(DROP(range,,1),,y)),",",SEQUENCE(,MAX(2+LEN(range)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range,",",""))))),","),2))),",",SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(range))),",")),UNPIVOT(A2:C5))
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be 6 (3 PersonnelArea x 2 PayScaleGroup) rows for Queensland ?

Comment: @SpectralInstance good catch, I needed `LEN(range)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range,",",""))` to be `+1` because the number of strings is equal to the number of delimiters +1. Simple fix (phew!)

Comment: This has come very close, the SQL gives me 196 rows for my dataset, this formula gives me 174.  It looks like it's getting confused with a scenario when the same calendar is listed twice in a row.  In my actual dataset, that is a possibility.  Why the business have maintained it like that isn't clear to me but very much a real possibility.  If you can manage to enhance it so it can deal with that, I'll flag this answer for sure.  It seems to perform well, is dynamic in nature and is the least intense from a visual perspective.  I updated my answer with more detail re: the data set.

Comment: ... on another note, blank cells also play funny buggers but I could let that slide.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I edited my answer to deal with duplicates. Not sure what you mean by blanks and how you expect the result to behave in such case.

Answer (score 2):

```
=LET(rng,A2:C5,
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(rng)),LAMBDA(x,y,
VSTACK(x,
LET(personnel,TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(INDEX(rng,,2),y),","),
payscale,TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(INDEX(rng,,3),y),","),
splitpayscale,COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(INDEX(rng,,3),y),",")),
DROP(REDUCE("",personnel,LAMBDA(u,v,VSTACK(u,
HSTACK(
IFNA(EXPAND(INDEX(INDEX(rng,,1),y),splitpayscale),INDEX(INDEX(rng,,1),y)),
IFNA(EXPAND(v,splitpayscale),v),
TOCOL(payscale))))),1)
))))
,1)
)
```

[image: SQL CROSS APPLY in Excel Formulas]

This formula works for 3 columns and many rows.

EDIT:
This suggestion uses the formula of contributor
[P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)
from this discussion:
[Generate All Permutations in Excel using LAMBDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71188880/generate-all-permutations-in-excel-using-lambda)

The formula works for several columns and rows and i've tested it for up to 8 columns and 7 rows however the calculation takes it's time depending on the database and computer performance.

```
=LET(range,A2:H8,z,COLUMNS(range),
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,LET(a, 
IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",INDEX(range,y,),
LAMBDA(u,v,HSTACK(u,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(v,","))))),,1),""),
b,  UNIQUE(TAKE(a,,1)),
r,  REDUCE(b,  SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(a)-1,2),
    LAMBDA(x,y,
    TOCOL(x & "," & TOROW(UNIQUE(INDEX(a,,y)))))),
s,DROP(REDUCE("",r,
 LAMBDA(x,y,
      VSTACK(x,
           TEXTSPLIT(y,",")))),
 1),
t,BYROW(s,LAMBDA(r,SUM(BYCOL(r,LAMBDA(c,N(LEN(c)>0))))=z)),
 FILTER(s,t)
)))),1))
```

[image: SQL Cross Apply EDIT Answer]

Answer (score 0):

This works for an arbitrary number of columns within the limits of the [stack space allowed for recursion](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/lambda-recursive-lists-and-understanding-recursion-limits-of/m-p/2199690) in Excel (but I think this may have been increased). The following function expands a single row (as displayed by the [Advanced Formula Environment](https://github.com/microsoft/advanced-formula-environment)):

```
=LET(
    cols, COLUMNS(Row),
    split, TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(Row, Depth), , ","),
    IF(
        Depth > cols,
        "",
        DROP(
            REDUCE(
                "",
                SEQUENCE(ROWS(split)),
                LAMBDA(a, c,
                    VSTACK(
                        a,
                        LET(
                            x, CrossApply(Row, Depth + 1),
                            s, SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),
                            DROP(
                                REDUCE(
                                    "",
                                    s,
                                    LAMBDA(ax, cx,
                                        VSTACK(ax, HSTACK(INDEX(split, c), INDEX(x, cx, 0)))
                                    )
                                ),
                                1
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            1
        )
    )
)
```

called as:

```
=CrossApply(Row,Depth)
```

where Row is the row array to be expanded and Depth is the current recursion depth, initially 1.

If you prefer a more conventional display:

```
=LAMBDA(Row,Depth,
LET(cols, COLUMNS(Row),
 split, TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(Row, Depth), , ","),
 IF(Depth > cols, "", 
  DROP(REDUCE("", SEQUENCE(ROWS(split)), LAMBDA(a,c, VSTACK(a, 
   LET(x, CrossApply(Row, Depth + 1), s, SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)), 
    DROP(REDUCE("", s, LAMBDA(ax,cx, VSTACK(ax, HSTACK(INDEX(split, c), INDEX(x, cx, 0)))))
    , 1)
   )))), 1)
)))
```

Looks like this in Name Manager:

[image]

and it can be repeated for an arbitrary number of rows by nesting it in another lambda:

```
=LET(
    data, A2:C4,
    s, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
    DROP(
        REDUCE(
            "",
            s,
            LAMBDA(a, c, VSTACK(a, CrossApply(INDEX(data, c, 0), 1)))
        ),
        1
    )
)
```

or in more compact form:

```
=LET(data,A2:C4,s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),DROP(
REDUCE("",s,LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,CrossApply(INDEX(data,c,0),1)))),1))
```

[image]

(adds an empty column which can be dropped).