Un-consolidate truth table in excel
I have a truth table that has been consolidated. This truth table is used to solve for what assembly is used based on a model nomenclature. Each row represents digit in the model number.
I wish to un-consolidate it so I may have a row for each unique configuration. This is shown below.

Here is an example of the first assembly number un-consolidated.

I have unsuccessfully tried a VBA script below, but am open to all options including a cell-based formula to try and solve:
Sub UnconsolidateList()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4) 'Change to your sheet number
    
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = lastRow To 4 Step -1
        Dim configs() As String
        configs = Split(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value, ",")
        
        Dim capacities() As String
        capacities = Split(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value, ",")
        
        Dim vents() As String
        generation = Split(ws.Cells(i, 5).Value, ",")
        
        Dim cases() As String
        factoryops = Split(ws.Cells(i, 6).Value, ",")
        
        Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, m As Integer
        
        For j = LBound(configs) To UBound(configs)
            For k = LBound(capacities) To UBound(capacities)
                For l = LBound(generation) To UBound(generation)
                    For m = LBound(factoryops) To UBound(factoryops)
                        If j + k + l + m > 0 Then 'Avoid duplicating the original row
                            lastRow = lastRow + 1 'Increment the row number where data will be inserted
                            ws.Rows(lastRow & ":" & lastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Insert a new row at the end of the list
                            
                            ws.Cells(lastRow - 1, "A").Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(lastRow, "A")   'Copy part no.
                            ws.Cells(lastRow - 1, "B").Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(lastRow, "B")   'Copy type

                            ws.Cells(lastRow, "C").Value2 = Trim(configs(j))
                            ws.Cells(lastRow, "D").Value2 = Trim(capacities(k))
                            ws.Cells(lastRow, "E").Value2 = Trim(generation(l))
                            ws.Cells(lastRow, "F").Value2 = Trim(factoryops(m))
                        End If
                    Next m
                Next l
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub


There are a number of formula solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77917473/sql-cross-apply-in-excel-formulas (including mine which sadly didn't get much attention!)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19780307/478884 has an approach for generating all combinations for a variable number of input lists: you might be able to use that to expand your listing.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.


You don't need to specify the columns containing combined items. A typical recursive function can handle all combinations without nested loop.

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Variant
    Dim arrData, arrRes, iR As Long, aRow() As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, aTxt
    Dim oColl As New Collection
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
    ' load source table
    arrData = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim aRow(ColCnt - 1)
    ' loop through each row
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        ' split all items
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            aRow(j - 1) = Split(arrData(i, j), ",")
        Next j
        GenerateCombinations oColl, aRow
    Next i
    ' populate output
    ReDim arrRes(1 To oColl.Count, ColCnt - 1)
    iR = 0
    For Each c In oColl
        aTxt = Split(c, "|")
        iR = iR + 1
        For j = 0 To UBound(aTxt)
            arrRes(iR, j) = aTxt(j)
        Next
    Next
    ' write output to new sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(, ColCnt).Value = oSht1.Range("A1").Resize(, ColCnt).Value
    Range("A2").Resize(iR, ColCnt).Value = arrRes
End Sub

Sub GenerateCombinations(ByRef oColl As Object, aVals() As Variant, Optional curStr As String = "", Optional colIdx As Long = 0)
    Dim i As Long
    ' If the current index equals the length of the array
    If colIdx = UBound(aVals) + 1 Then
        '        Debug.Print curStr
        oColl.Add Mid(curStr, 2)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Loop through each element in the current array and recursively call GenerateCombinations
    For i = LBound(aVals(colIdx)) To UBound(aVals(colIdx))
        GenerateCombinations oColl, aVals, curStr & "|" & aVals(colIdx)(i), colIdx + 1
    Next i
End Sub



This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    
//type all columns as text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(colNames, each {_, type text})),
    
//transform all columns to Lists except for the first column (Assembly #)
    #"Transform to List" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", 
        List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(colNames,1), (cn)=> {cn, each Text.Split(_,","), type {text}})),

//Expand the lists
    #"Expand Lists" = List.Accumulate(
        Table.ColumnsOfType(#"Transform to List",{type list}),
        #"Transform to List",
        (s,c)=> Table.ExpandListColumn(s,c))
in
    #"Expand Lists"


Non-recursive approach:
Sub ExpandListing2()

    Dim rw As Range, arr, i As Long, col As Collection, res
    Dim cStart As Range, ws As Worksheet, lr As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set cStart = ws.Range("I2") 'output starts here
    
    'process each row in input table
    For Each rw In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:G" & lr).Rows
        arr = rw.Value
        Set col = New Collection
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            col.Add Split(arr(1, i), ",") 'split each cell value to an array (1+ elements)
        Next i
        res = Combine(col)
        'write the result to the sheet
        With cStart.Resize(UBound(res, 1), UBound(res, 2))
            .Value = res
            .Font.Color = IIf(rw.Row Mod 2 = 0, vbBlue, vbRed) 'color this block
        End With
        Set cStart = cStart.Offset(UBound(res, 1)) 'next output start position
    Next rw
End Sub



'Create combinations from a collection of arrays
'return as a 2D array
Function Combine(col As Collection)

    Dim rv() As String
    Dim pos() As Long, lengths() As Long, lbs() As Long, ubs() As Long
    Dim t As Long, i As Long, n As Long, ub As Long
    Dim numIn As Long, s As String, r As Long, v, tmp()

    numIn = col.Count
    ReDim pos(1 To numIn)
    ReDim lbs(1 To numIn)
    ReDim ubs(1 To numIn)
    ReDim lengths(1 To numIn)
    t = 0
    For i = 1 To numIn  'calculate # of combinations, and cache bounds/lengths
        'handle cases where only one value in a column (not passed in as array)
        If Not TypeName(col(i)) Like "*()" Then
            ReDim tmp(1 To 1)
            tmp(1) = col(i)
            col.Remove i
            If i > col.Count Then
                col.Add tmp
            Else
                col.Add tmp, before:=i
            End If
        End If
        lbs(i) = LBound(col(i))
        ubs(i) = UBound(col(i))
        lengths(i) = (ubs(i) - lbs(i)) + 1
        pos(i) = lbs(i)
        t = IIf(t = 0, lengths(i), t * lengths(i))
    Next i
    ReDim rv(1 To t, 1 To numIn) 'resize destination array

    For n = 1 To t
        For i = 1 To numIn
            rv(n, i) = col(i)(pos(i))
        Next i
        For i = numIn To 1 Step -1
            If pos(i) <> ubs(i) Then   'Not done all of this array yet...
                pos(i) = pos(i) + 1    'Increment array index
                For r = i + 1 To numIn 'Reset all the indexes
                    pos(r) = lbs(r)    '   of the later arrays
                Next r
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next n

    Combine = rv
End Function

Example:

